# Reflection color (Blender 2.8)

Tags: materials, color, reflection

Where do I find the Blender 2.8x equivalent of the "Mirror reflection color" found in 2.7x (as in picture)[image]?

Comment: Why so many arrows and drawing to mark. label? Does red and blue stroke color means something?

Answer (score 0):

To use Glossy node and change color to pink?

[image]